# How to get the next item in ng-repeat for an object?

Tags: angularjs, object, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an object as follows:

```
scope.items = {
"poor-John-1": {
    "_id": "poor-John-1",
    "name": "poor-John-1",
    "sName": "room-poor-John-2"
},
"poor-John-2": {
    "_id": "poor-John-2",
    "name": "poor-John-2",
    "sName": "room-poor-John-2"
}

}
```

I have rendered the object in the following way

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items | orderObjectBy: '_id' track by item._id"  ng-class="getStyle(item, next_item)"><td>{{item.sName}}</td></tr>
```

What I want to do is, pass, the current and next_item to the getStyle function, since its not an array, $index is not pointing the value. I have data in object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can do this with

```
$scope.keys = Object.keys($scope.items) // put keys on scope

// get next from keys
<tr ng-repeat="(key, item) in items track by item._id"  ng-class="getStyle(item, items[keys[$index +1]])">
  <td>{{key}}</td>
  <td>{{item.name}}</td>
  <td>next : {{items[keys[$index +1]]}}</td>
  </tr>
```

Look this, tell me if it's what you want https://plnkr.co/edit/GCNmWb9Qv2mntqTnGsX1?p=preview